# Sylius Role Permissions - Remove Inventory Management

Tags: permissions, sylius

I'm working with Sylius, and have been trying to create a user role that is allowed ONLY to edit products. I've given it the following permissions:

- Show Products
- List item
- Edit Product

No other permissions are applied, and no parent permission categories are checked. I'd think that these restrictive permissions would give that user role only access to the 'products' menu in administration, but it seems to also add the 'Inventory Levels' menu. This user role should absolutely not be able to see or edit inventory levels, so what gives?

Is this a bug with Sylius permissions? Have the permissions just not been expanded enough to allow for that fine level of control? Or is it thought that inventory levels are such an integral part of products, that it's always included in product-related permissions so that the administrator can ensure that the product they edit is actually available?

I'll accept solutions to remove inventory permissions, thought I presume I'll be getting my hands dirty in the code to do this. I'll also accept insights into the thinking behind this, or whether or not this is a bug with Sylius. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in the code. The file is: src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Menu/BackendMenuBuilder.php

This is the file that's placing all those items on the admin menu sidebar, after checking that permissions allow that user to see it. There's a chunk of code in here that looks like this:

```
if ($this->rbacAuthorizationChecker->isGranted('sylius.product.index')) { // THIS IS IT!
        $child->addChild('products', [
            'route' => 'sylius_backend_product_index',
            'labelAttributes' => ['icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'],
        ])->setLabel($this->translate(sprintf('sylius.backend.menu.%s.products', $section)));
        $child->addChild('inventory', [
            'route' => 'sylius_backend_inventory_index',
            'labelAttributes' => ['icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks'],
        ])->setLabel($this->translate(sprintf('sylius.backend.menu.%s.stockables', $section)));
    }
```

This adds the products menu item, and also adds the inventory menu item at the same time, based on the same permission: 'sylius.product.index'. I guess this either hasn't been separated into its own permission yet, or it is just thought that in MOST cases, a user who can manage products should also be able to manage inventory. I'll be creating a new permission for this to solve my issue.